# Where does Bandcamp app store its cache?

Tags: cache

[Bandcamp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bandcamp.android) refuses to install on an external SD card. It also doesn't offer an option to save its cache anywhere else than the main flash of my phone. So it either clogs my phone storage within days or, if I reduce the amount of storage it can use, allows me to listen just one or two albums when offline.

So I thought of finding the cache of that app on my phone, moving it over to the SD card and link it with good old Unix "ln -s" command back to the place, where Bandcamp will expect it to be.

1. Where can I find the audio cache of that app?
2. What are my chances for this hack to work?

Comment: Is the device rooted? The cache is normally saved in the data directory of an app which is under `/data/data/<PKG_NAME>/cache/`

Comment: Ok, I found it. I'll try to relocate the audio cache. Let's see what happens.